# Is it possible to focus on nothing in tvOS?

Tags: tvos

I'd like my app to start out without anything focused initially.  [This airbnb article](http://nerds.airbnb.com/tvos-focus-engine/) suggests that it's possible for focus to be nil: `UIScreen.mainScreen().focusedView // possibly nil`.  Is there a way to set it so, or request the focus to be nil?

I don't think setting the preferredFocusView to nil would do this, because I think that just means that there's no preferred focus...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the API does support that, since it goes against the whole idea of giving navigation context to the user with the Focus Engine.

This is from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/WorkingwiththeAppleTVRemote.html):

> If your app uses built-in UIKit controls, there is nothing your app needs to do to support focus out of the box: When the app launches, a focusable control onscreen is chosen as the initial focused view, and the focus engine takes care of managing focus for you for the lifetime of the app.
>
> When an app launches, by default the focus engine determines a starting focused view for you. This view is usually the closest focusable view to the top-left corner of the screen.

A possibility could be to have a view outside the boundary of screen and return that view in your `preferredFocusView`-method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to have a nil focused view.  However, it's often something that you want to avoid.  In the simplest case, if none of the views in the view hierarchy can become focused, there won't be a focused view.